# Azure Storage Queue triggers a Function App, but it never qeques

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-storage-queues

When I insert into my Storage Queue a triggered is invoked which executes a Function App. The function then performs some logic on that data. This is working just fine.

Question is this:
**How can the Function App dequeuer/delete the message from the queue?** 
Currently a trigger is invoked but the data still remains in the queue.

**In addition, if the triggered message is somewhere in the middle of the queue, how can it delete it from the queue (since a queue is FIFO)?**

*** Update ***

After observing the queue using the Azure Storage Explorer tool, I can see the message arrive into the queue, but then gets removed. I assume the automatic queue trigger automatically removes the message from the queue??

Comment: Take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40006372/azure-function-and-storage-queue-what-to-do-if-function-fails. Basically, on successful processing the message is removed from the queue. Any dequeued message is invisible to others for a given amount of time, hence the observation that it is not visible in the Azure Storage Explorer.

Comment: If a message is dequeued, why would it need to be invisible, since it has been removed in the first place?

Comment: dequeue is something else than remove. the process that has dequeued a message decides it won't handle it it will be picked up later. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/storage-dotnet-how-to-use-queues#de-queue-the-next-message